# Keep Removing last div

Tags: jquery

I need to remove last div and add a new div once I CLICK ON "Click here..."
 [Check it at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethar1/8FU7f/)

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
    $('#newsid div:last').fadeOut()
    $( "<div id='three'>test</div>" ).insertBefore( "#newsid div:first" ).fadeIn();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: And what's your question/problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fadeOut you don't remove the div, only make it hidden.

try changing

```
$('#newsid div:last').fadeOut()
```

for

```
$('#newsid div:last').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `callback function` as a parameter in `fadeout` function:

```
    $('#newsid div:last').fadeOut(
      function(){
        this.remove();
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you mean something like this by saying "only once": 
http://jsfiddle.net/8FU7f/1/

```
var doOnce = true;
$( document.body ).click(function() {
    if(doOnce) {
        doOnce=false;
        $('#newsid div:last').fadeOut()
        $( "<div id='three'>test</div>" ).insertBefore( "#newsid div:first").fadeIn();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
    $('#newsid div:last').fadeOut()
    $('#newsid div:last').remove()
    $( "<div id='three'>test</div>" ).insertBefore( "#newsid div:first" ).fadeIn();
});
```

The problem is, if you're using fadeOut(), there is always a div:last, but with "display:none" property.

Comment: You probably want to call `.remaove` *after* the element was faded out, not immediately, like in your code. You have to pass a callback to `.fadeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
$('#newsid div:last').fadeOut(300, function(){$(this).remove()});;
$( "<div id='three'>test</div>" ).insertBefore( "#newsid div:first" ).fadeIn();
});
```

Reasons are allready explained above. Fadeout does not remove it, I included the remove() code in a function after your fadeout.

Answer (score 0):

Use [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) then only use `:last selector` like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8FU7f/5/)

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
    $('#newsid div:visible:last').fadeOut()
    $( "<div id='three'>test</div>" ).insertBefore( "#newsid div:first" ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Otherwise :last selector would select the hidden last div also.